# Azure VMSS Custom Ubunutu Image outgoing(?) traffic blocked

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

I have a virtual machine scale set I deployed using a custom vhd(that I deprovisioned with `sudo waagent -deprovision+user`). I'm able to SSH into it, but I'm not able to access anything on the internet outside the VMs network. If I do a ping to google.com it looks like the packets are sent, but none are received. If I try to use curl it just sits there waiting forever.

I'm able to ping other vms within the scaleset though.

When it was just a VM not inside a scaleset I was able to access resources outside the network. I've had this working before so I'm not sure what I did wrong this time. There is nothing in the network security group that would be blocking any outgoing connections as far as I can tell.

Comment: Have you create vmss with Load balancer? public LB or internal LB?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT it was created with a public LB. I had another VMSS in another resource group on the same subnet I think. I deleted that and I think it's working now? I also had a virtual network gateway in another resource group that I deleted at the same time so I'm not sure which one fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Is the load balancer sku "basic" or "standard"? We recently GAed Standard load balancer, and some tooling defaults to it now. You can check in the azure portal by navigating to the load balancer, then checking under the "properties" tab. If you're using standard load balancer, you need to create a load balancer rule on the LB to enable outbound connectivity. Alternatively, you can enable public IP per VM in the scale set to achieve the same effect. More details on this behavior can be found in the "outbound connections" section of this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-overview#why-use-standard-load-balancer

Hope this helps! :)